# Reorder divs on media query with line break

Tags: html, css

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pusnv7d1/) to essentially what I want to do - reorder divs using floating to float the middle div to the left on smaller screen sizes, and the outer two to the right.

Here's the current order:

```
<div id='one'></div>
<div id='two'></div>
<div id='three'></div>
```

In addition to what's already there, I want the outer two divs to sit underneath the middle div on the left. Essentially I want it to look like:

```
<div id='two'></div>
<div id='one'></div>
<div id='three'></div>
```

Where div two has display:block, and display one/three have display:inline-block - *without changing the html*.

Is this possible with just CSS?

Comment: Please, post the image which shows your desire order in small screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done:

```
<div class="boxes"> 
    <div class="one box">Box One</div> 
    <div class="two box">Box Two</div> 
    <div class="three box">Box Three</div> 
    <div class="four box">Box Four</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) { 
    .boxes {  
    display:table; 
    width:100%; 
} 
.box { 
    display:block; 
    width:100%; 
} 
    .three { display:table-caption; } 
    .four { display:table-header-group; } 
    .one { display:table-footer-group; } 
}
```

Source: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2013/06/css/css-stacking-with-display-table (check the demo linked)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was after. Good old tables.